# Wordpress - rewrite fake urls

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I created a fake page in wordpress, that i catch with this code:

```
if ($_GET['fake_page'] == "myfakepage") {
  add_filter('the_title','plugin_myown_title');
  add_filter('the_content','plugin_myown_content');
  add_action('template_redirect', 'plugin_myown_template');
}
```

this works correctly.
Now what I'd like to do is to rewrite such this url

```
my_site?fake_page=myfakepage
```

in

```
my_site/product/myfakepage
```

where product is an existing page created from wordpress dashboard.

I followed this guide:

http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html

and defined this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^fake_page=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$       my_site/product/%1      [NC,L,R=301]
```

but what i get is

```
my_site/product?fake_page=myfakepage
```

where is the problem?
Besides I would like to know if typing into browser:

```
my_site/product/myfakepage
```

i could make wordpress treats it as

```
 my_site?fake_page=myfakepage
```

without any redirect.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code from your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'product/myfakepage/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?fake_page=myfakepage',
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Note: you do not need that custom .htaccess. BTW: you souldn't modify .htaccess directly, never. There is an extensive [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) in WordPress which allows you to apply custom rules.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, it return a 404 error. Could the problem be related to the fake page? If I put your rule into .htaccess it goes right.

Comment: How exactly is your "fake_page" implemented? Via hook? To what?

Comment: It's just a function into functions.php which contain the only IF in evidence in my question. The function is then called into 404.php